# Ios intune Sdk Integration

Tags: ios, sdk, intune

I have an Ios application that uses ADAL to authenticate but I need to integrate Intune Ios SDK, though I have followed the steps but it doesn't seem to be working. Do I need to call the delegates as well?
And do I need to request for policy in `appDelegate` even if I am calling `registerAndEnroll` after successful authentication?

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: Hi @Babul & Savanna did both of you able to find any solution for this???

Comment: No. I didn't find any @Ashish